# Ubuntu Server install on Annapurna Labs CPU

Tags: server, arm

I know that Ubuntu supports ARM processors. I mean, I got it to install on a Pi 4 but I've not been able to reliably find good solid information on installs that support Annapurna Labs ARM CPUs

is this CPU supported on Server??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will my device work with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/986878/will-my-device-work-with-ubuntu)

Comment: There are two supported ARM architectures ... why not look up what architectures the device you're interested in will run & see if there is a match?  Also why not boot & try it... numerous images exist (*though some are only for testing & not released products*).   This is a Q&A site & what you're asking is the sort of *opinion* question that is off-topic here as it belongs on a Forum (which this site isn't). https://ubuntuforums.org/ is the site of Ubuntu Forum(s).

Comment: Amazon’s Graviton instances are powered by Annapurna Labs ARM CPUs, so the answer is clearly “yes”. That said, you will need a special image that is optimized for the architecture. Canonical’s [cloud image page](https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/jammy/current/) might be a good place to start 

Comment: @guiverc I miss how this is opinion-based. The question is "is this CPU supported or not". The answer may be "yes", "no", or "it's complicated", but I can't think of a scenario where the answer would be "it depends on what's right for you".

Comment: @ArrayBolt3  Discussion(s) I've had with mods ... I saw this as like "*Questions that are primarily opinion-based, such as shopping or hardware recommendations*" (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) are best dealt with on forums & not Q&A sites like this.   I call things how I see/understand them (*and won't always be right!*)

Comment: @matigo I had no idea there was a ""cloud image"" that might do the trick.

Comment: @guiverc its a QNAP Device that has one and was given to me , and I get mixed answers on it